# Repeated Addition

Tags: java, addition

I just got a task asking me to do repeated addition from 1 to 21, as follows :

1,4,6,9,11,14,16,19,21
and get the total.

I tried this code but it returned to be a +2 addition, and it even bypass the prerequisite of bil<=21

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {

        int bil=1;
        long total=0;
        boolean mult = true;

        for(bil=1; bil<=21;bil++)
        {
            if(mult=true)
            {
                bil+=1;
                mult=false;
            }
            else if(mult=false)
            {
                bil+=2;
                mult=true;
            }
    System.out.println(bil);
    total=total+bil;
        }
    System.out.println("----+");
    System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```

(if it's TL;DR)

Basically the request is 1+4+6+9+11+14+16+19+21=?

I can't seem to get these code to work, please help me?

EDIT : Thanks guys I got it now :D

Comment: Java naming convetion uses Capital letter to start class name.

Comment: Well you are either adding 3 or adding 2 to the preceding value. Therefore for even n, f(n) = 3 + f(n-1), and for odd n, f(n) = 2 + f(n-1), with f(1) = 1.

Comment: Don't really get what you are trying to do, but `mult=false` is an assignment, not a check. You probably mean `==`.

Answer (score 1):

You need `boolean mult = false;` so that the first time the loop runs, `bil` is incremented by 3 and not 2.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are not comparing your boolean with `==`.  Therefore, every time the `for()` loop executes, the first block will be the one that enters since `mult = true` will always store `true` in `mult`... and then qualify that `if()` block to run.

If this assignment wasn't intentional, then you need to change it to `==` and also put some logic in your loop to toggle `mult` appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Basically when it runs through the first loop it only adds one because of the state of the boolean but also there should be an == operator to check instead of just an =

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (bil = 1; bil < 21; bil++) {

   if (bil % 2 == 0) { // If bil is divisible by 2, then add 2
      bil += 2;
      continue;     
   }

   bil += 3;

}
```